# How to communicate with a wifi chip from a iphone

Tags: iphone, wifi

I have a wifi chip which i want to connect from the iphone and send data to it. How do i do this ? Ideas or sample code or possibilities of this are appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean "communicate with a WiFi chip"?  Are you referring to ad-hoc mode?  In any case, all wireless communications are handled by the iPhone OS.

Answer (score 0):

Install the iPhone SDK on your Mac to get the development tools.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/

Comment: i have the iphone sdk. I understand how to communicate between two iphones, since an iphone will publish a service and can be detected. how will it detect a wifi chip. does a wifi chip have a fixed name or ip to be detected. how can i do this ?

Comment: All iPhones have a wifi-chip.  Elabolrat in your question what you need to "detect", how you expect to do it, and what you need it for.  Your question right now is incomplete.

Comment: if we have two iphones we can communicate, but if one is a iphone and other is a wifi chip then in that case how do you detect the wifi chip and communicate with it ?

Comment: I do not believe that the iPhone supports ad-hoc networking, so you need both systems to attach to a wireless router and get TCP/IP working.